# Django bulk_update not working on default attributes

Tags: python, django, sql-update, bulk

I want to change the default value of an attribute from a model in Django. So I want to update the existing values in the database. Strange enough, a bulk update doesn't change those values.

My model:

```
class UserSettings(models.Model):
    offline_notification_filter = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My test

```
class TestSetOfflineNotificationMigration(APITestCase):
    def test_set_offline_notification_filter_to_false(self):
        user_settings_1 = UserSettingsFactory(offline_notification_filter=True)
        user_settings_2 = UserSettingsFactory(offline_notification_filter=False)
        user_settings_3 = UserSettingsFactory(offline_notification_filter=True)
        user_settings_4 = UserSettingsFactory()

        all_user_settings = UserSettings.objects.all()
        for user_setting in all_user_settings:
            user_setting.offline_notification_filter = False
        UserSettings.objects.bulk_update(
            all_user_settings, ["offline_notification_filter"]
        )

        self.assertEqual(user_settings_1.offline_notification_filter, False)
```

This test is failing because the the offlince_notification_filter is not updating. Anyone knows why not?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are working with outdated instance, so you might need to `user_settings_1.refresh_from_db()`.

Answer (score 0):

`bulk_update()` is not necessarily needed in this case. Since this update operation is being performed directly on all objects of queryset, so just using `update()` will automatically make changes in a single operation.

Bulk update is more suited to operations where instances of different models are being updated.

However if you still prefer to use `bulk_update`, then here's the answer:
`user_settings_1` is an in-memory instance here, whereas bulk_update operation has made the change in database. You need to refresh it from database.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_update

You need to provide an array of the models to update, and specify the fields you want to update.

I would suggest the following code:

```
class TestSetOfflineNotificationMigration(APITestCase):
    def test_set_offline_notification_filter_to_false(self):
        user_settings_1 = UserSettingsFactory(offline_notification_filter=True)
        user_settings_2 = UserSettingsFactory(offline_notification_filter=False)
        user_settings_3 = UserSettingsFactory(offline_notification_filter=True)
        user_settings_4 = UserSettingsFactory()

        all_user_settings = UserSettings.objects.all()
        # Create list to append new models
        new_user_settings = []
        for user_setting in all_user_settings:
            # Create new model with the updated fields
            new_user_setting = UserSettings(offline_notification_filter=False)
            # Append
            new_user_settings.append(new_user_setting)

        # Response is amount of models updated
        q = UserSettings.objects.bulk_update(
            new_user_settings, ["offline_notification_filter"]
        )

        self.assertEqual(q, 4)
```

If you have a long set of fields to update, you can update the fields with the _meta method and create the list of fields to update like:

```
# Get list of fields
fields = [f.name for f in UserSettings._meta.fields]

# delete the ones you don't want to update with Sets
list_of_fields = fields - {"id"}

q = UserSettings.objects.bulk_update(
                new_user_settings, list_of_fields
            )
```